# How to add marker on the map using the location name

Tags: java, android

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap){
    map = googleMap;
    LatLng tinching = new LatLng(22.3290803, 114.1478785);
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(tinching).title("Sham Shui Po"));
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(tinching));
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(tinching,15));
}
```

Hi all, How can I add a marker on the map using the location name(such as London) instead of input the Latitude and Longitude?

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to use Geocoder (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) to get lat and long of city by name.

```
    if(Geocoder.isPresent()){
try {
    String cityName= "NameOfTheLocation";
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
    List<Address> addresses= geocoder.getFromLocationName(cityName, 5); // get the found Address Objects

    List<LatLng> latlng = new ArrayList<LatLng>(addresses.size()); // A list to save the coordinates if they are available
    for(Address a : addresses){
        if(a.hasLatitude() && a.hasLongitude()){
            latlng .add(new LatLng(a.getLatitude(), a.getLongitude()));
        }  
    }  
} catch (IOException e) {
     // handle the exception
}}
```

Then use your latlng to add marker

```
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).title("Sham Shui Po"));
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng));
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlng,15));
```